# Call getNextException to see the cause : How to make Hibernate / JPA show the DB server message for an exception

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I am using Postgresql, Hibernate and JPA. Whenever there is an exception in the database, I get something like this which is not very helpful as it does not show what really went wrong on the DB server.

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 update foo set ALERT_FLAG='3' was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1837)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2754)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 82 more
```

I want the exception message from the database to appear in the application's log.

I came across [this article](http://erics-notes.blogspot.in/2008/03/java-sqlexception-chaining.html) which uses an Aspect to populate the exception chain which is otherwise not populated properly in case of SQLExceptions.

Is there a way to fix this without using Aspects or any custom code. Ideal solution would involve only config file changes.

Comment: How are you outputting the exception?  My experience with log4j and slf4j, I get the caused by lines for free...

Comment: Logging libraries do print the cause but they do so if the excption follows the exception chaining convention. i.e. each exception should return its immediate root cause through getCause() method. Apparently, SQLException does not follow this convention. The article I've linked explains the same. The author has therefore written an aspect which takes the object returned by getNextException() and sets it as the cause in the parent exception.

Comment: @Priyank `SQLException` uses an exception chain (which can be iterated over with an iterator or using `getNextException()`) when multiple (unrelated?) exceptions occur. This concept is orthogonal to the cause-chain. In this specific example I do think it should have been set as the cause though.

Comment: I am looking for a better solution than writing custom code. This problem (of not being able to see the DB message), I think, is too common to not have a more elegant solution.

Comment: ryanp is right but his answer is verbose: in short because of batch insert you should have an ERROR line in your logs (above your stacktrace) from `SqlExceptionHelper` with the cause, ex: `null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to write any custom code to achieve this - Hibernate will log the exception cause by default. If you can't see this, Hibernate logging must not be set up correctly. Here's an example with slf4j+log4j, and using Maven for dependency management.

**src/main/java/pgextest/PGExceptionTest.java**

```
public class PGExceptionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                "pgextest");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        // here I attempt to persist an object with an ID that is already in use
        entityManager.persist(new PGExceptionTestBean(1));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

**src/main/resources/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n
```

**src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="pgextest">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pgextest"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="5"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pgextest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pgextest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Executing the main method will then log the following:

```
ERROR [main] - Batch entry 0 insert into PGExceptionTestBean (label, id) values (NULL, '1') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
ERROR [main] - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pgexceptiontestbean_pkey"
```

It's probably worth mentioning that you can disable the JDBC batching that wraps the original exception by setting the property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to `0` (needless to say you probably don't want to do this in production.)

Comment: Yes! I knew what the exception message was to be expected so searched that in the console log and I found one tiny line with the message. So, it does show up but without the bells and whistles of a complete stack trace. That's good enough for me.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this in Play 2.2.x? It uses logback for logging

Comment: In my case "java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 delete from account where id=32 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause..."
org.slf4j+log4j  was the solution. Log level has to be set to DEBUG to see the root cause.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me to get the exception message which caused the problem (Hibernate 3.2.5.ga):

```
catch (JDBCException jdbce) {
    jdbce.getSQLException().getNextException().printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you can directly go with, `catch (SQLException e) { e.getNextException().printStackTrace(); }`

Answer (score 5):

I think Aspect Programming is a better solution to solve this kind of problem.

But, if you want to write a custom code to do that, you can catch SqlException and loop through it and log each exception. Something like this should work.

```
try {
 // whatever your code is
} catch (SQLException e) {
    while(e!= null) {
      logger.log(e);
      e = e.getNextException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not look right at all. You are calling getNextException three times for every exception!!

Comment: You can optimize it to one by taking variable out... but technically there is nothing wrong in it.. it will give you same exception since it's a get...

Comment: @Victor Grazi was correct the first time. `getNextException()` gets a different exception every time it is called until it finally returns null.

Comment: If you're going to recommend your favorite programming paradigm, perhaps at least include an example of that paradigm, or leave it out of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For me the exception was a PersistenceException, so I had to do this:

```
try {
//...
} catch (javax.persistence.PersistenceException e) {
    log.error(((java.sql.BatchUpdateException) e.getCause().getCause()).getNextException());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
 // code
} catch (SQLException e) {      
  for (Throwable throwable : e) {
        log.error("{}", throwable);
  }
}
```

Comment: Love the idea. The placeholders don't get replaced for me on log4j 1.2.15 so I'll write my own message to go with the traces.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if it so happens that you are getting this exception from inside a JUnit test you can transform the JUnit exception with a `TestRule` (this is was inspired by the source of `ExpectedException` `TestRule`)

```
public class HibernateBatchUnwindRule implements TestRule {

    private boolean handleAssumptionViolatedExceptions = false;

    private boolean handleAssertionErrors = false;

    private HibernateBatchUnwindRule() {
    }

    public static HibernateBatchUnwindRule create(){
        return new HibernateBatchUnwindRule();
    }

    public HibernateBatchUnwindRule handleAssertionErrors() {
        handleAssertionErrors = true;
        return this;
    }

    public HibernateBatchUnwindRule handleAssumptionViolatedExceptions() {
        handleAssumptionViolatedExceptions = true;
        return this;
    }

    public Statement apply(Statement base,
            org.junit.runner.Description description) {
        return new ExpectedExceptionStatement(base);
    }

    private class ExpectedExceptionStatement extends Statement {
        private final Statement fNext;

        public ExpectedExceptionStatement(Statement base) {
            fNext = base;
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            try {
                fNext.evaluate();
            } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {
                optionallyHandleException(e, handleAssumptionViolatedExceptions);
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                optionallyHandleException(e, handleAssertionErrors);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                handleException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void optionallyHandleException(Throwable e, boolean handleException)
            throws Throwable {
        if (handleException) {
            handleException(e);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private void handleException(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        while (cause != null) {
            if (cause instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
                BatchUpdateException batchUpdateException = (BatchUpdateException) cause;
                throw batchUpdateException.getNextException();
            }
            cause = cause.getCause();
        };
        throw e; 
    }
}
```

and then add the rule to the test case

```
public class SomeTest {

    @Rule
    public HibernateBatchUnwindRule batchUnwindRule = HibernateBatchUnwindRule.create();

    @Test
    public void testSomething(){...}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If by some chance you are encountering this exception from Kafka-Connect, you can set the batch.size property to 0 (temporarily) to reveal the exception encountered by your sink worker.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I was using java and `postgreSQL` database I got this exception. After checking the record which I tried to `insert` to the `table`, it was found the record had duplicate id and it violated unique constraints. Therefore it is better to check record that you are going to `insert` and try to `insert` it using db client to see extract error.