# POSTGRESQL: Batch entry 0 SELECT

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have the following method which calls a stored function in postgresql. The call works when I use a standard executequery() method but does not work when I start using batchs. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public void addstuff3() throws Exception {
 Statement statement = null;
  ResultSet resultSet = null;
  Connection conn = null;
      try {
      // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      conn = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/newmydb?"
              + "user=new_user&password=password");

   // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = conn.createStatement();
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
     statement.addBatch("SELECT ADDSTUFF('comp1',     'mdel1','power','PROPERTY','STRING','ON', '1396983600000', 'testing');");
     statement.addBatch("SELECT ADDSTUFF('comp2',     'mdel2','power','PROPERTY','STRING','ON', '1396983600000', 'testing');");
     conn.commit();
     statement.executeBatch();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
       conn.close();
    //   resultSet.close();
       statement.close();

    }
```

This is the Error I get:

```
Batch entry 0 SELECT ADDSTUFF('comp1', 'mdel1','power','PROPERTY','STRING','ON',     '1396983600000', 'testing') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
at     org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Sta    tement.java:2743)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1.handleError(QueryExecutorImpl.java:461)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1928)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405)
at     org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2892)
at jdbc.testing.MySQLAccess.addIndicators3(MySQLAccess.java:125)
at jdbc.testing.JDBCTesting.main(JDBCTesting.java:21)
```

Any help? I am using jdbc and postgresql.

Comment: you are committing before executing the batch. There may be other issues but that's the first thing which stood out to me. Also you close your statement/connection in the wrong order (and you're not doing null checks when you do)

Comment: Incidentally, did you follow the advice in the error and call `getNextException` to see the cause?

Comment: I had trouble with that how can I print that info out.

Comment: A quick search turns up this which looks helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848359/call-getnextexception-to-see-the-cause-how-to-make-hibernate-jpa-show-the-db

Comment: Actually it seems even simpler than that; it's just a method on the exception you catch: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getNextException() (call that and log the result in your catch block, or just re-throw the result for simplicity since you don't seem to have a logger configured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thanks to @Dave I found that

```
e.getNextException()
```

1. Prints:

   ```
    A result was returned when none was expected
   ```
2. I should not return a value

Works!

Comment: Ah yes, quite right; a batch is for adding/modifying/removing records/tables, not retrieving data.